# input behaviour in browsers

Tags: css

how to make inputs look like the same in every browser?

how can you make buttons or inputs look like the same in every browser? in firefox the padding is behaving different than ie and chrome

```
input.btn {
    border:1px solid #23458c;
    background:url('gfx/layout.btn_bg.png');
    color:#f0f5fa;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:6px;
    padding:1px 5px 2px 5px;
    [if Gecko] padding:0px 5px 1px 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

### edit

```
input.btn {
    border:1px solid #23458c;
    background:url('gfx/layout.btn_bg.png');
    color:#f0f5fa;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:6px;
    padding:1px 6px 2px 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Comment: At a guess is the issue resolved when you remove this line.
[if Gecko] padding:0px 5px 1px 5px;

Comment: I was assuming that was his way of showing *us* that if the browser rendering engine is Gecko he wants to use that padding. I'd hope it's not in his real CSS, anyway.

Comment: @david.. thats right.. I want to do something like this

Comment: was my answer of any use to you? Is it still not working as you'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox adds some inner padding for it's dotted focus effect which you may need to remove.

```
input.btn::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: this works, but then you can't see which input has focus.. how can you add more padding in all browsers then Firefox?

Comment: I don't know, you'd probably have to use a CSS hack. It would be better to just add your own focus style.

Comment: great solution.. didn't know that :focus existed :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this is due to the varying ways in which form elements are handled by the different browsers. You could try adding:

```
-moz-box-sizing: content-box; /* or border-box */
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
```

to your CSS styles for the buttons, this should force all browsers to use the same box model, after which the padding rules should apply the same cross-browser.

Comment: I can't make it work... I just need add these three lines in the bottom of my css file?

Comment: If you add those lines to the CSS declarations for the `input` element it *should* work. Unless there's something else going on.

Comment: @clarkk, are you able to post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces this behaviour?